# Is it possible to refactor a custom method at Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google Sheets. I added some custom functions and used it for my calculations within a sheets.
Now I'd like to fix functions' names. Is there any way to change functions' names and to get these names updated in sheets automatically?

Answer (score 0):

you can change them but they won't be auto-updated.

best you can do is to use **find & replace** by pressing **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>H</kbd>**

[image]